# KML layer not showing up

Tags: kml

I am creating vector layers in format KML. I have the sources in drop box to avoid CORS, but when I load them in the map they have no features. Any ideas about this issue will be very much appreciated.

Please see below how I am doing it.

```
var layers = [ 

wms_bmid_pipes = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ea4qzzuyk5i2mxt /geid_ws-bmid-pipes.kml?dl=0',
            format: new ol.format.KML() 
            })
        })
        ];
```

Since the layer does not show up in the map I ran the code below to check how many features it has (this code comes from the open layers web site). It turns out that in the console I get "Count after change: 0" , meaning that there are no features.

```
    wms_bmid_pipes.getSource().on('change', function(evt){
        var source = evt.target;
            if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
                var numFeatures = source.getFeatures().length; 
                console.log("Count after change: " + numFeatures);
            }
    });
```

The point is that the wms_bmid_pipes  contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
<Document>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>-119.3597596329119</longitude>
        <latitude>49.89850519575446</latitude>
        <altitude>19983.5008834143</altitude>
        <heading>0.0</heading>
        <tilt>0.0</tilt>
        <range>16147.716881798802</range>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    </LookAt>
    <NetworkLink>
        <name>bmid-pipes</name>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <open>1</open>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-119.3597596329119</longitude>
            <latitude>49.89850519575446</latitude>
            <altitude>19983.5008834143</altitude>
            <heading>0.0</heading>
            <tilt>0.0</tilt>
            <range>16147.716881798802</range>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <Url>
            <href>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geid_ws/wms?service=wms&amp;request=GetMap&amp;version=1.1.1&amp;format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&amp;layers=geid_ws:bmid-pipes&amp;styles=line&amp;height=2048&amp;width=2048&amp;transparent=false&amp;srs=EPSG:4326&amp;format_options=AUTOFIT:true;KMATTR:true;KMPLACEMARK:false;KMSCORE:40;MODE:refresh;SUPEROVERLAY:false</href>
            <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
            <viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
            <viewRefreshTime>1.0</viewRefreshTime>
            <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
        </Url>
    </NetworkLink>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

[KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) requires the KML be publicly available.   `http://localhost:8080` is not publicly available.

```
<Url>
    <href>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geid_ws/wms?service=wms&amp;request=GetMap&amp;version=1.1.1&amp;format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml&amp;layers=geid_ws:bmid-pipes&amp;styles=line&amp;height=2048&amp;width=2048&amp;transparent=false&amp;srs=EPSG:4326&amp;format_options=AUTOFIT:true;KMATTR:true;KMPLACEMARK:false;KMSCORE:40;MODE:refresh;SUPEROVERLAY:false</href>
    <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
    <viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
    <viewRefreshTime>1.0</viewRefreshTime>
    <viewBoundScale>1.0</viewBoundScale>
</Url>
```